# Running several regressions with changing outcome variable in R

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, tidyverse

I have a dataframe (df) that looks like the following:

```
condition  dv1  dv2  dv3
1          2    4    3
2          5    7    4
3          7    1    2
```

In order to run several regressions simultaneously, I have used code like this:

```
dfdv <- df[,2:4]  
output <- lm(as.matrix(dfdv) ~ condition, data = df)
summary(output)
```

This gives me all the dv ~ condition regressions for dv1, dv2, and dv3. These are the regressions that are given in the output:

```
dv1 ~ condition
dv2 ~ condition
dv3 ~ condition
```

However, I would now like to control for different conditions in the regression. Specifically, I would like to figure out a way to run the following regressions efficiently.

```
dv1 ~ condition + dv1
dv1 ~ condition + dv2
dv1 ~ condition + dv3
```

I tried the following using a similar principle to what worked above, and it didn't work.

```
dfdv <- df[,2:4]  
output2 <- lm(dv1 ~ condition + as.matrix(dfdv), data = df)
summary(output2)
```

It gave me a single regression using all the dv's in that one regression as opposed to the regressions that I wanted. This is what it gave me:

```
dv1 ~ condition + dv1 + dv2 + dv3
```

Does anyone know how I can perform these regression analyses using simple code? I have several more in my actual dataset than I am including in this example.

Comment: I think this question would benefit from more realistic example data which can be used to generate output from regression.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lapply` for that.  Loop through the column names that are 'dv', create formula with `reformulate` by specifying the response and dependent variable, and apply the `lm`

```
v1 <- grep('^dv\\d+$", names(df), value = TRUE)
lapply(v1, function(dv) lm(reformulate(c(dv, "condition"),
           dv), data = df))
```

---

Or create the formula with `paste`

```
lapply(v1, function(dv) lm(paste0(dv, " ~ ", "condition + ", dv), data = df))
```

Comment: Could you please explain what paste0 and reformulate do?

Comment: @melbez  Sure, give me a min

Comment: Does this work if the names of the outcome variables don't all start with "dv"?

Comment: @melbez  As I showed in the example, you can change the 'v1' to whatever you wanted.  i.e. `v1 <- colnames(df)[3:4]` etc.

Comment: When using "dv" as an input to function() and in reformulate, what is dv referring to? I see where v1 comes from but don't see where dv comes from.

Comment: @melbez  When you do `function(x) x` it is anonymous lambda function which returns the values of 'v1' ie. here it would be 'dv1', 'dv2', 'dv3'.  If you have doubts, please check with a print `lapply(v1, function(dv) dv)`

Comment: I have tried both methods and keep getting this error:  Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
  invalid term in model formula

Comment: @melbez You can check reproducible example `lapply(names(iris)[-5], function(dv) lm(reformulate("Species", dv), data = iris))`

Comment: I'm unfortunately still unable to determine what's causing the error message. It's the same error message when I try both approaches you proposed.

Comment: @melbez  Sorry, I can't reproduce the issue.  I showed with an example that is clearly reproducibe.

Comment: @melbez  When you do `lm("dv1 ~ condition + dv1", data = df)` does it work? The `paste` step is also creating a formula in `lm` (similar to `lm("Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Species", data = iris)`)